# Implementing Secure Access to Liferay 7.4 Page from External Mobile App with OAuth or Custom Filter

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-7.4

we are using liferay 7.4 and separate native mobile app.

we have to provide the access to Liferay page when request is coming from mobile app which is already logged in.

Liferay should accept token from mobile app and allowing into Liferay page.

Not sure OAuth will fit in this case.  Here is the use cases:

1. We have created Liferay Page , For ex: http:///web/xxxx/page1
2. Mobile Application ( external, not related to Liferay ) will include above liferay url inside their mobile page after user login into Mobile app ( no connectivity between mobile app user and liferay user )
3. Before user access that liferay page inside Mobile App , there should be a handshake mechanism between Liferay and Mobile Application, then only Liferay should display that page.

can anyone confirm oauth will fit in above scenario?  or we should go for custom filter implementation ?

Comment: As you mention "no connectivity between mobile app user and liferay user" it's unclear to me whom you'd like to authenticate on the Liferay side.

Comment: It means , Mobile Application users are not connected with Liferay Users. we are not storing any mobile user's information into liferay and vice versa. User will login into Mobile App and should access the Liferay authenticated page without passing any user details , but any other oAuth token.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to "authenticate" an anonymous user through OAuth?

Comment: Yes Olaf . External website / Mobile app should authenticate into Liferay through Oauth

Comment: Can we go with below approach                                                                          
 Liferay will register the external website/mobile app as an OAuth client.              
 Liferay will provide the external application with a client ID and client secret.                  The external application will utilize Liferay's OAuth token to request an access token.                                                                                                                              With the access token, the external application will be able to enter Liferay application